# Center DIV horizontally and fixed distance from top or bottom, no scrolling in window

Tags: html, css, css-position

Say I have a div that I want to be centered horizontally, and set at a fixed distance from the top or bottom of the window.  I want to set its width to say 75%, and its height to be fluid depending on dynamic content. The page will never have content extending past the viewport so it won't ever scroll.  How can I do this with CSS?  HTML is here, basically:

```
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="div_in_question">
      Omg stuff goes here it will probably change though via jQuery.
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why would you absolutely position this? You should position it relatively, it will behave much better for what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VGRYG/)

HTML

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    height: 300px;
    width: 75%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    margin-left: -37%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

Explanation: give `position: absolute;` to your `div` and the real trick to get it centered horizontally is give `margin-left` which will be half of your total width of the `div` and give `left` as `50%` to bring it horizontally centered

Comment: Here's the page: http://new.e17.paca.arvixe.com/  For some reasion I can't get this to work.  It's close, but you can see if you resize the window a little that it's not perfectly centered, but appears closer to the right side of the window (at least in Chrome).  Any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: @NaOH it is because you are using all absolute positioned `div`

Comment: Oh?  What's that got to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

You can divide up the page width like so:

```
margin-left:14.5%;
margin-right14.5%;
width:75%;
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you keeping the distance from the top or bottom fixed, irrespective of the amount of content in the div?

If so, you can try something like this:

```
<div id='outer'>
     <div id='inner'>                    
         SOme text hereSOme text hereSOme text hereSOme text hereSOme text hereSOme  
     </div>
</div>
```

and the css classes:

```
#outer{
height:150px;
background-color:red
}

#inner{
width:75%;
height:auto;
background-color:yellow;
max-height:100%;
overflow:hidden;
margin-left:14.5%;
margin-right:14.5%
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hbRHW/